# Mixed superscript, subscript and widehat

Tags: accents, subscripts, superscripts

What is the correct way to write this equation and make both L_s matrices look the same? I tried this but the widehat and superscript L_s matrix' subscript is positioned slightly lower than the no-widehat no-superscript L_s.

```
\dot{\mathcal{L}} = - \lambda \mathbf{e}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{L}_\mathbf{s} \widehat{\mathbf{L}_s^{+}} \mathbf{e}
```

UPDATE:

This is the code output for me. Note that the first subscript s is higher than the second.

[image: Code output]

This is more noticeable when regular font size is used:

[image: Regular font size]

This minimal example seem to produce correct output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\cramped{\mathbf{L}_\mathbf{s}}
\widehat{\mathbf{L}_\mathbf{s}^{+}}
\]
\end{document}
```

But when used inside my document (thesis) it produces the output described above. I have no idea what causes this, but it's probably some other obscure configuration of the cls file I'm using (from the thesis reference model).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The slight difference is in the fact that TeX uses "cramped display style" when typesetting the argument to `\widehat`, which is characterized by reduced lowering of subscripts and raising of superscripts.

This is one of the cases where TeX needs help; here's a way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\cramped{\mathbf{L}_\mathbf{s}}
\widehat{\mathbf{L}_\mathbf{s}^{+}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, don't let the wide hat cover also the superscript and subscript:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathbf{L}^{}_\mathbf{s}
\widehat{\mathbf{L}}_\mathbf{s}^{+}
\]
\end{document}
```

Notice the empty superscript.

[image]

Comment: First time seeing the use of that command `cramped`. Could you elaborate on what it is doing, that is go a little bit deeper?

Comment: The first suggestion made no changes to me. But even if I could make it work like it did for you, for text-wide consistency, I'd have to use \cramped in all other matrices in my text. Your second suggestion, with wide hat covering only the L makes them look the same, but may imply different meanings. The hat is for estimation, so estimating L and then pseudo-inverting it is different from estimating the pseudo-invert directly.

Comment: I also tried removing the wide hat and keeping only the superscript + and their indices look different too. So it might not be related to the wide hat at all, but with the use of super- and subscript together.

Comment: @perr0 Did you notice the empty superscript in the first one?

Comment: @egreg I think you misplaced the empty superscript. It's actually part of the second one. Yes, it really works and I've noticed that with the empty superscript I don't even have to use \cramped. Anyway, I'd still have the text-wide consistency problem. But it definitely makes them look better, as the problem is much more apparent when both are together. So it might be a good workaround. What about the \cramped? As I see it's not really necessary here.

Comment: @perr0 I don't follow you. Without the empty superscript in the second example the subscripts wouldn't be vertically aligned. The `\cramped` in the first example isn't *really* necessary; it is if there is a superscript. However, the problem only appears when two such symbols are next to each other.

Comment: @egreg Sorry for my confusion. I think that when you said _first one_ I understood _first example_ (the one with \cramped), but there is no empty superscript in there and that confused me. Clearing up: With my question's code, the **s** subscript of L_s^+ is slightly lower than the one in L_s. So: **1** Your first example (\cramped) makes no difference to me. **2** Your second example looks good, but changes the meaning of the matrix. **3** Using only an empty  superscript lowers the **s** subscript of L_s^+. Although the other subscripts-only matrices in my text would look different from this

Comment: I tried this example from mathtools manual: `\[ \cramped{x^2} \leftrightarrow x^2 \quad ]\` and they really produce different results. But `\[ \cramped{L_s} \leftrightarrow L_s \quad ]\` produce identical outputs (at least to my eyes). @egreg, I noticed in your first example that the **s** subscript in L_s^+ is higher than mine and your code is the same (you just added the \cramped in the L_s matrix). Mine is definitely different, as it appears lower than the on in L_s.

Comment: This is getting to my nerves! I tried this minimal example `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\cramped{\mathbf{L}_\mathbf{s}}
\widehat{\mathbf{L}_\mathbf{s}^{+}}
\]
\begin{equation}
\dot{\mathcal{L}} = - \lambda \mathbf{e}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{L}_\mathbf{s} \widehat{\mathbf{L}_\mathbf{s}^{+}} \mathbf{e}.
\end{equation}
\end{document}` and it looks correct (as egreg's first example) but when using inside my document it produces a different output, as described. I have no idea what is causing it.

Comment: @egreg You're right, the \cramped does make a difference. It's better noticed using \Huge. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You could also construct superscripts/subscripts independent from one another:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \mathbf{L}_\mathbf{s}
  \widehat{\rlap{$\phantom{\mathbf{L}}_{\mathbf{s}}$}\mathbf{L}^{+}}% Subscript then superscript
  \mathbf{L}^{+}% For comparison
  \widehat{\mathbf{L}^{+}}% For comparison
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a phantom superscript "`+`" to the no superscript L:

```
\( \mathbf{L}_\mathbf{s}^{\phantom{+}} \widehat{\mathbf{L}_\mathbf{s}^{+}}\)
```

Comment: It makes them look the same, but for text-wide consistency, I'd have to use this phantom superscript in all other matrices in my text. I really don't want to do that.